# Iterate Though IEnumerable<String> to populate List<DTO> MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, dto

Can anyone help with a problem i have, im trying to write a method that will return a list of my DTO objects

I am getting the user by the usrCode and and the getting a list of their jobCodes in the DB.  Then i am getting a list of All Jobs from WCF. I then want to make a new list with the jobDescription attached the DTO as the DB only has userCode and jobCode.   What i want is a list of JobDescription from my WCF but from a list of Jobs a user DOESNT have. via this....

```
List<UserJobsDTO> list = listBuilder(jobs, yetToHave);
```

Currently i have only this, i have managed to get a list of jobCodes a user doesnt have but i need jobDescriptions...  Can anyone help me complete my method?

```
 public ActionResult addJob(string usrCode)
    {
        var jobs = jobsClient.GetAlljobs();
        var alljobsCode = (from s in jobs select s.jobsCode).ToList();
        var thisUserJobCode = (from s in db.UserJobs
                                   where s.usrCode == usrCode
                                   select s.jobsCode).ToList(); 
        var yetToHave = alljobsCode.Except(thisUserJobCode);
        List<UserJobsDTO> list = listBuilder(jobs, yetToHave);
        ViewBag.jobsCode = new SelectList(list, "jobsCode", "jobDescription");
        var model = new UserJob { usrCode = usrCode };
        return View("addJob", model);
    }

    private List<UserJobsDTO> listBuilder(jobsService.jobsDTO[] jobs, IEnumerable<string> yetToHave)
    {
        foreach (string s in yetToHave)
        {
           for every yetToHave job
           attach description to UserJobsDTO.Description
        }
    }
```

DTO:

```
public class UserJobsDTO
{
    public String userCode { get; set; }
    public String jobsCode { get; set; }
    public String jobDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: where is jobDescription exist  ? How is connected to jobCode ? Show us the sample response coming from WCF Service

Comment: They are in the UserJobsDTO.  

`public class UserJobsDTO
    {
        public String userCode{ get; set; }
        public String jobsCode{ get; set; }
        public String jobDescription { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: Something like `foreach (string s in yetToHave) { s.Description = jobs.Where(j => j.jobCode == s.jobCode).Single().ToString(); }` might do the trick.  This assumes that `jobCode` is unique.

Comment: Yeah its unique but the yetToHave is IEnumerable<string> of jobCode not Description so that wouldnt work

Answer (score 2):

You can use the LINQ `Contains` method  with `!` ( *That means not contains*)

Assuming `jobsClient.GetAlljobs()` returns a collection of `UserJobsDTO` DTO.

```
//Get all Jobs
var allJobs = jobsClient.GetAlljobs().ToList();

//Get a list of Job code this user
var thisUsersJobCodeList = (from s in db.UserJobs where s.usrCode == usrCode
                               select s.jobsCode).ToList(); 

//Get items from all jobs except the items in thisUsersJobCodeList 
var yetToHave = allJobs.Where(s => !thisUsersJobCodeList .Contains(s.jobsCode)).ToList();

//Convert to a List<SelectListItem> for dropdown
var dropDownData = yetToHave.Select(s => new SelectListItem 
                                 { Value = s.jobsCode, Text = s.jobDescription}).ToList();

ViewBag.jobsCode = dropDownData;
```

Comment: What would be passed to the view??.  That solution also throws this error Error 5 Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable.   For allJobs variable

Comment: Your existing code i guess. ViewBag.jobs has the item you wanted

Comment: var allJobs = jobsClient.GetAlljobs().ToList();

Comment: What does `jobsClient.GetAlljobs()` s type ?

Comment: jobsService.jobsDTO[] JobServiceClient.GetAllJobs()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101478/discussion-between-bean-shares-and-shyju).