# MVC passing to View type issue with dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass through to the view a dropdown list, the list is comprised of two lists. One list of jobCode a user has and a list of all available jobCodes.  I am trying to pass into the view a third list which is of all the jobCodes a user DOESNT have via a dropdown list but i keep getting this issue...

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]',
 but this dictionary requires a model item of type 
 System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[UserJobs]'.



public ActionResult addJob(string useCode)
{
    var jobs = jobsClient.GetAlljobs();
    var alljobsCode = (from s in jobs select s.jobCode).ToList();
    var thisUserJobCode = (from s in db.UserJobs
                               where s.useCode == useCode
                               select s.jobCode).ToList();
    var notObtained = alljobsCode.Except(thisUserJobCode);
    ViewBag.jobCode = new SelectList(notObtained, "jobCode", "jobDescription");

    return View(notObtained.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Looks a lot like this question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/34966533/745969 - but not an exact duplicate.  Sounds like a homework assignment....

Answer (score 1):

The data in variable `alljobsCode` is a list of jobCode property value which i believe is of string type. So `notObtained` variable will also have the same type because you call the `Except` method on the alljobscode variable and set the result of that to the `notObtained` variable,  which is a collection of string(*specifically* `IEnumerable<string>`). You are passing this collection of strings to the view.

It seems that your razor view is strongly typed to a collection of `UserJob` class. So you need to make sure that you are returning a collection of that instead of a collection of string.

What you should do is, create a new view model with  properties needed for the view.

```
public class AddJobToUserVm
{
  public string UserCode { set;get;}

  //properties for the dropdown 
  public List<SelectListItem> JobsNotAddedYet { set;get;}
  public string SelectedJob { set;get;}

  // The below property is for listing existing jobs already added to the user
  public List<string> JobsOfUser {set;get;}
}
```

and in your GET action, initialize an object of this view model and send to the view. I hard coded the values of different properties. You may replace it with your real values from db.

```
public ActionResult AddJob(string userCode)
{
    var vm = new AddJobToUserVm {UserCode = client};
    vm.JobsNotAddedYet = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Value = "JobCode1", Text = "Job 1"},
        new SelectListItem {Value = "JobCode2", Text = "Job 2"}
    };
    vm.JobsOfUser = new List<string>() {"Job 25", " Job 26"};
    return View(vm);
}
```

And your view will be strongly typed to this new view model

```
@model AddJobToUserVm
<h2>Already added job for the user</h2>
@foreach(var item in Model.JobsOfUser)
{
 <p>@item</p>
}
<h3>Add new Job to user</h3>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  <label>Select Job </label>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.SelectedJob, Model.JobsNotAddedYet, "Please select")
  @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.UserCode)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: The Razor view is automatically scaffolded by going to Add/View/List.  Would there be a way around doing it  that way?

Comment: Do you really want to show 3 dropdown lists in the view ?

Comment: Im not its just notObtained, which is a single list that has all of the already obtained jobs removed.

Comment: I am not quite following what you want. Take look at the update i posted. It should take care of rendering a dropdown.